# The price of Maple Syrup Scientists

Tags: evil-genius-2

When you try to acquire the [Maple Syrup](https://evilgenius.fandom.com/wiki/Maple_Syrup_Dispenser), you need to run a specified scheme: Syrup Heist/Vol Du Sirop. For this part of the scheme series, 10 Guards, 2 Valets, 15 intel, and **6989 Gold** are required. Besides this one scheme, as far as I can tell, all schemes require full thousands.

Is this some kind of documented easter egg or reference in the game?

[image]

Comment: I would assume it is some kind of reference to the real life heist (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Canadian_Maple_Syrup_Heist), but I can't figure out any way 6989 relates to it.